# Creating Flutter Shopping Cart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a Shopping Cart in my App ,
can i have some sources on how to do it ?

All i have watch is old and not what i want
which is to use Firebase and Provider

This is the model:

```
class Summer_d {
  late String Imag;
  late String info;
  late String name;
  late int price;
  late String sub_info;
  late List<dynamic>? sub_img;

 

  Summer_d.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic>data){
    Imag = data["Imag"];
    info = data ["info"];
    name = data ["name"];
    price = data["price"];
    sub_info = data ["sub_info"];
    sub_img = data ["sub_img"];

    
    

  }
}
```

This is the Provider class

```
class SummerNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Summer_d> _summerList = [];
  late Summer_d _currentsummer;

  int slectedIndex = 0;

  UnmodifiableListView<Summer_d> get summerList =>
      UnmodifiableListView(_summerList);

  Summer_d get currentsummer => _currentsummer;

  set summerList(List<Summer_d> summerList) {
    _summerList = summerList;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set currentsummer(Summer_d summer_d) {
    _currentsummer = summer_d;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community! your question is very broad. I would like to know what exactly is your problem? like you have a problem with building the entire shopping cart and you need a tutorial or you have a particular problem with one part of your app?

Comment: I dont have a problem with my app i just want to know the method of how to create a sopping cart since im new to flutter and this is my first app

Comment: creating a shopping cart is more than just a method, it's more into it. maybe you can check this https://medium.com/codechai/flutter-using-simple-setstate-to-build-a-shopping-cart-example-a4ce0e57c9d2

Comment: I know its more than just a method i meant the way to do it + thanks man i will check it